# Optimisation: loops vs summing generator comprehensions

Tags: python, optimization

During today's Google Code Jam (specifically, on '[The Repeater](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2994486/dashboard)'), I ran into the following odd performance difference between two snippits of code.

For the snippits below, assume `lengths` is a list of positive integers.

When using the following code (somewhere nested inside a loop), my solution runs in roughly 3.1 seconds.

```
minmov = -1
for target in range(101):
    mov = 0
    for l in lengths:
        mov += abs(l - target)
    if mov < minmov or minmov == -1:
        minmov = mov
moves += minmov
```

However, when I replace it with the functionally equivalent snippit seen below, it suddenly takes 4.2 seconds. A whooping 33% increase!

```
moves += min(sum(abs(l - t) for l in lengths) for t in range(101))
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is so significantly slower? To the casual observer, it is not immediately obvious why this is doing something different.

Comment: You're tracking the `min` value as you iterate in the former.  In the latter it takes another pass.  How many elements in `lengths` (order of magnitude)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's standard lib `cProfile` module to see where the time is being consuming in your code. I wrapped the code with a minimum working example and profiled it (not sure if it mimics exactly the behavior of the algorithm but I hope it is useful to make my point):

#### Code:

```
import random
moves = 0
lengths = [random.randint(-10,10) for _ in range(101)]

def foo():
    global moves
    minmov = -1
    for target in range(101):
        mov = 0
        for l in lengths:
            mov += abs(l - target)
        if mov < minmov or minmov == -1:
            minmov = mov
    moves += minmov

def foo2():
    global moves
    moves += min(sum(abs(l - t) for l in lengths) for t in range(101))

import cProfile
cProfile.run("foo2()")
#cProfile.run("foo2()")
```

#### Profile iterative:

```
python t.py
         10205 function calls in 0.023 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.023    0.023 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.013    0.013    0.023    0.023 t.py:5(foo)
    10201    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {abs}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
```

#### Profile functional:

```
python t1.py
         10409 function calls in 0.023 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.047    0.047 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.047    0.047 t.py:16(foo2)
      102    0.000    0.000    0.047    0.000 t.py:18(<genexpr>)
    10201    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {abs}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.047    0.047 {min}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
      101    0.012    0.000    0.046    0.000 {sum}
```

On my PC (Windows, Python2.7) they almost run at the same speed, but notice how many more function calls does the *functional code*. Function calls in Python are expensive, sometimes is preferably stick with loop and a simple solution.

By looking at the profile dump, `sum` is being call 101 times, in your iterative solution, you do this by using the `+=` operator so no function is called.

The functional code move the loops to C, but does so at the cost of `101` (or maybe this 101 just means the lenght of `lengths` so it would be at the cost of `len(lengths)`) **more function calls**.

I bet this is what is causing the additional overhead. You can read Guido's excellent [Python Patterns - An Optimization Anecdote](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/) essay to have more info on this topic.

I'm not completely sure about `min` having to iterate the whole array again to extract the minimum as mentioned in the comments. The functional solution is based on generators. The outer generator, `min` in this case, is the engine that move all the machinery of generators.

When `min` starts, it will try to find the first element on the generator passed as argument, this in turn will wake the `sum` method and start the sum's argument generator, yielding `abs(l[0] - 0)` as the first value of the `sum`'s argument generator, doing so until the whole sum `abs(l[0]-0) + abs(l[1]-0)...` is calculated, then that will be the first value of the `min`'s argument generator. `min` will keep track of it when it moves to check the second element in its argument generator and so on.

Implicitly, `min` is actually keeping track of the minimum value because you're working with *generators* not *list comprehensions*.

Hope this helps!